# How do you use collection initializers to create a new dictionary?

Tags: c#

If you can do this in List

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() {
   2, 4, 6, 8, 10
};
```

how can you do the same thing in Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<int, bool> b = new Dictionary<int, bool>() {
   ?, ?, ?
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to initialize a C# dictionary with values already in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047602/proper-way-to-initialize-a-c-sharp-dictionary-with-values-already-in-it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, bool> b = new Dictionary<int, bool>() {
   {1, true},{2, false},{3, true}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

MSDN has an article on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

You just wrap each key-value pair in curly brackets.

Comment: awesome! Thanks too! I wish I could click the check image for you both  Travis and @Josh