# Proper way to initialize a C# dictionary with values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary in a C# file with the following code:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, XlFileFormat> FILE_TYPE_DICT
        = new Dictionary<string, XlFileFormat>
        {
            {"csv", XlFileFormat.xlCSV},
            {"html", XlFileFormat.xlHtml}
        };
```

There is a red line under `new` with the error:

> Feature 'collection initilializer' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification

What is going on here?

I am using .NET version 2.

Comment: Change targeted framework version or use the "old" way of initialization.

Comment: In what context do you place this code? A `.cs` file that gets compiled by Visual Studio, or in a `.cshtml`? Does your [project file have a `languageVersion` element](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/issues/detail?id=1)?

Answer (score 1170, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue in a simple .NET 4.0 console application:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "key1", "value1" },
            { "key2", "value2" }
        };

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Can you try to reproduce it in a simple Console application and go from there? It seems likely that you're targeting .NET 2.0 (which doesn't support it) or client profile framework, rather than a version of .NET that supports initialization syntax.

Comment: The issue is the version of C# the OP is using, object/collection initializers weren't introduced until C# 3.0. The detail as to why it didn't work before has already been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459652/why-do-c-sharp-collection-initializers-work-this-way).

Comment: How do I check what version of C# I'm using or change it?

Comment: The project's properties will indicate the target version of the framework.

Comment: The version of Visual Studio you are using is usually a good indicator - see here for [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c).

Comment: @James - Not reliably, however, as this person may be picking up some legacy work in a solution that was targeting 2.0 and isn't aware of it, for example.

Comment: if you're using .net 4.0 why not just write it with inline assembly?

Answer (score 342):

With C# 6.0, you can create a dictionary in the following way:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    ["one"] = 1,
    ["two"] = 2,
    ["three"] = 3
};
```

It even works with custom types.

Comment: I like your way betther, but take notes that it uses the exact same number of "boilerplate" characters per line (4) as the accepted answer with { "key2", "value2" },

Comment: Works in c# 3.1 too.
var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>
                {
                    ["Abc"] = 2d
                }

Comment: That's a new syntax I wasn't familiar with. Thanks.

Comment: Note, on duplicate keys this syntax does not throw whereas the other does ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer))

Comment: I didn't know this syntax, thanks. It makes it easy to copy and paste dictionaries of data from other languages such as Lua.

Answer (score 47):

You can initialize a `Dictionary` (and other collections) inline. Each member is contained with braces:

```
Dictionary<int, StudentName> students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>
{
    { 111, new StudentName { FirstName = "Sachin", LastName = "Karnik", ID = 211 } },
    { 112, new StudentName { FirstName = "Dina", LastName = "Salimzianova", ID = 317 } },
    { 113, new StudentName { FirstName = "Andy", LastName = "Ruth", ID = 198 } }
};
```

See *[How to initialize a dictionary with a collection initializer (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer)* for details.

Comment: For what versions of C#? Was it there with the first version or was it introduced later?

Comment: I like that you did **_not_** use `var` or `Add()`.

Answer (score 46):

Suppose we have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "Mohan");
dict.Add(2, "Kishor");
dict.Add(3, "Pankaj");
dict.Add(4, "Jeetu");
```

We can initialize it as follows.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "Mohan" },
    { 2, "Kishor" },
    { 3, "Pankaj" },
    { 4, "Jeetu" }
};
```

Comment: The ReSharper answer.

Answer (score 16):

Note that C# 9 allows [Target-typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) so if your variable or a class member is not abstract class or interface type duplication can be avoided:

```
    private readonly Dictionary<string, XlFileFormat> FILE_TYPE_DICT = new ()
    {
        { "csv", XlFileFormat.xlCSV },
        { "html", XlFileFormat.xlHtml }
    };
```

Answer (score 14):

Object initializers were introduced in C# 3.0. Check which framework version you are targeting.

[Overview of C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

With С# 6.0

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["Key1"] = "Value1",
    ["Key2"] = "Value2"
};
```

Comment: Your answer (before it was edited by Turbcool) was an exact copy of the accepted answer by Haney. Please ensure future answers provide *new* solutions to questions.

Comment: @TylerH The answer was unique, as I have suggested the indexer-based approach(Used variables from accepted answer). But the answer was not a copy. Please refer to the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Dictionary with Dictionary value

```
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> result = new() {
                ["success"] = new() {{1, "ok"} ,  { 2, "ok" } },
                ["fail"] = new() {{ 3, "some error" }, { 4, "some error 2" } },
            };
```

which is equivalent to this in JSON :

```
{
  "success": {
    "1": "ok",
    "2": "ok"
  },
  "fail": {
    "3": "some error",
    "4": "some error 4"
  }
}
```