# Add arrays to a higher dimension array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am creating an app that gets information and download movies from a site. I have succeeded in setting the information in different arrays and combining them together to 1 array.

However, now I am trying to put that array inside a bigger array (want to work with JSON), and that is failing.

My current Json output looks like this:

```
 {"moviedata": 
    ["http:/xxxx","title title ","k0X0HrYtMm5u"],"tags": 
    ["x","x","x","Prop","x","x","x","x","x","x","x"],"categorydata": 
    ["x","x","x"]}
```

Which is achieved with this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> movie = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

moviedata.Add("moviedata", moviegenerala);
moviedata.Add("tags", tagsa);
moviedata.Add("categorydata", categoriesa);
string moviejson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(moviedata);
```

I want to add another layer on top of this, so there is a general tab named "Movie", and for each movie it has this information. How would I do that?

UPDATE:
Added this code:

```
var myShape = new
    {
        Movie = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            ["moviedata"] = moviegenerala,
            ["tags"] = tagsa,
            ["categorydata"] = categoriesa,
            ["localdata"] = localdataa
        }
    };
    var moviejson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myShape);
```

The JSON seems to be correct, but it cannot parse, after the first listing it says there is text after the closing bracket.

UPDATE:
Changed code to this:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> movies = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
                                var myShape = movies.Select(m => new
                                {
                                    Movie = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
                                    {
                                        // TODO - you'll need to get the appropriate data for this movie
                                        ["moviedata"] = moviegenerala,
                                        ["tags"] = tagsa,
                                        ["categorydata"] = categoriesa,
                                        ["localdata"] = localdataa
                                    }

                                });

                                var moviejson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myShape);
                                File.AppendAllText("moviedata.txt", moviejson);
```

But now it only gives empty brackets :(

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off serialization, then simplest could be just to wrap the Dictionary with an anonymous class adding the extra property indentation, e.g.

```
var myShape = new 
{
     Movie = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
     {
         ["moviedata"] = moviegenerala,
         ["tags"] = tagsa,
         ["categorydata"] = categoriesa
     }
};
var moviejson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myShape);
```

However, if this same shape is required in multiple places in your code, then I would recommend that you create a fully fledged class for your 'Shape'.

**Edit:**

The json produced by the above is

```
{
  "Movie": {
    "moviedata": [ "http:/xxxx", "title title ", "k0X0HrYtMm5u" ],
    "tags": [ "x", "x", "x", "Prop", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x" ],
    "categorydata": [ "x", "x", "x" ]
  }
}
```

If you need to map multiple Movies, then project then you can use a `.Select`:

```
// TODO : Replace this with your actual current movies
var inMovies = new[] {new Movie{...},new Movie {...}, ...};
var myShape = inMovies.Select(m => new
{
    Movie = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
    {
        // TODO - you'll need to get the appropriate data for this movie, e.g. m.moviegenerala
        ["moviedata"] = moviegenerala, 
        ...
    }
});
```

Produces the following:

```
[
  {
    "Movie": {
      "moviedata": [ "http:/xxxx", "title title ", "k0X0HrYtMm5u" ],
      "tags": [ "x", "x", "x", "Prop", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x" ],
      "categorydata": [ "x", "x", "x" ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Movie": {
      "moviedata": [ "http:/xxxx", "title title ", "k0X0HrYtMm5u" ],
      "tags": [ "x", "x", "x", "Prop", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x" ],
      "categorydata": [ "x", "x", "x" ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of using the more concise [C#6 dictionary initializer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28434818)

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to work fine for the first value. However, subsequent movies that are added no longer parse as valid JSON, says text after final closing bracket..

Comment: Just gives empty brackets now :(

Comment: We're missing eachother totally here. You haven't really shown your input data. The `inMovies` parameter represents your existing collection of movie data that you want to re-shape.

Comment: Hmmm, but there is no movie data at the start of the run.. Everything is fresh and every movie should be added just once

Comment: Right now every movie is added 4 times :(