# new Dictionary { [person] = person } which version of c# supports this syntax?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is it possible to instantiate a `Dictonary` in C# using the following syntax:

```
Person person = new Person();
var dictionary = new Dictionary { [person] = person };
```

If yes, then what version of C# supports it?

Currently I am running Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, but it does not support this syntax.

Comment: Perhaps `Dictionary<int, Person> dictionary = new() { [1] = person };` [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047602/proper-way-to-initialize-a-c-sharp-dictionary-with-values)

Comment: either `Dictionary<string, Person> dictionary = new() { {"person", person} };` or `var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Person> { {"person", person} };`?

Answer (score 0):

you should write your code as blow :

```
Person person = new Person();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,person>() { "person" , person };
```

You can even write like this

```
Person person = new Person();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,person>() { "person" , new person {....}};
```