# Cant initialize a dictionary list in c# in abstract class where dictionary is static

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, abstract-class, initializer-list

i have this abstract class where i try to initialize dictionary with Objects
but someone it wont let me

```
public abstract class ICharacterBody3DState
{
    
    public static Dictionary<StateInput, ICharacterBody3DState> State = new Dictionary<StateInput, ICharacterBody3DState>()
    {
        StateInput.sprint=new StateInput(),

    };

}
```

Each state is inheriting from this abstract class :

```
public class WalkingState : ICharacterBody3DState
{
}
```

but it gives me :
CS0747: Invalid initializer member declarator.
is there any way to initilize the abstract class Dictionary with Objects ?

Comment: You need to initialize a Dictionary with Key Value pairs. So a pair of instances of  StateInput and ICharacterBody3DState. What you are trying with the assignement in the initializer is beyond me. Thats not how it work. The docs have sample that should give you the idea https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer

Comment: [How to initialize a dictionary with a collection initializer (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer). Usually interface names start with an uppercase "I".

Comment: What is `StateInput.sprint=new StateInput(),` supposed to mean? Which is the Key, and which is Value of the dictionary entry you're trying to add? Did you mean the [newer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28434818/1043380) `[key] = value`?

Comment: C# 6 added collection initializers for associative collections (e.g. dictionary) with two syntaxes. The syntax `{ StateInput.sprint, new StateInput() },` calls `Add(TKey, TValue)` and the syntax `[StateInput.sprint] = new StateInput(),` calls `Item[TKey]`. The behavior is different when a key is duplicated in the initializer. `Add()` will fail when the key already exists. `Item[]` will overwrite the prior value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class ICharacterBody3DState
{
    public static Dictionary<StateInput, ICharacterBody3DState> State = new Dictionary<StateInput, ICharacterBody3DState>()
    {
        { StateInput.sprint, new StateInput() },
    };
}
```

put each key and value inside curly braces `{}` and separated them with a `comma`. This is the right way to add items to your dictionary.

Comment: this is the answer wired its not written in the documents , only to do k=v